# using variable (f)-string stored in json

Tags: python, json, pandas, pyspark, config

I have a json config file where I store my path to data there

The data is bucketed in month and days, so without the json I would use an f-string like:

```
spark.read.parquet(f"home/data/month={MONTH}/day={DAY}")
```

Now I want to extract that from json. However, I run into problems with the Month and day variable. I do not want to split the path in the json.
But writing it like this:

```
{
    "path":"home/data/month={MONTH}/day={DAY}"
}
```

and loading with:

```
DAY="1"
MONTH="12"
conf_path=pandas.read_json("...")
path=conf_path["path"]
data=spark.read_parquet(f"{path}")
```

does not really work.

Could you hint me a solution to **retrieving a path with variable elements** and filling them after reading? How would you store the path or retrieve it without splitting the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use string.format() instead of `f-strings`

Still if you want to use f-strings then you should use `eval` like this, its unsafe

```
DAY="1"
MONTH="12"
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [{
    "path":"home/data/month={MONTH}/day={DAY}"
 },
 {
    "path":"home/data/month={MONTH}/day={DAY}"
 }
]
)
a = df['path'][0]
print(eval(f"f'{a}'"))
#home/data/month=12/day=1
```

Comment: Great, I will check it out ASAP. Could you explain further why f-string is unsafe? I thought exactly for safety reasons you should use f-string?

Comment: f-string is safe. What is not safe is eval part.

Comment: f-string work by substituting the value where the string is located so when you are reading it from file then it will expect that that variable should be in the file but since that file is json so you can't keep variables there thatswhy f-string is not working previously. Here also firstly we get the string and then we are saying it to evaluate the f-string here using variables initialised in this file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Deepak Tripathi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74114580/5446749), the answer is to use string format. Like this:

```
day="1"
month="12"
conf_path=pandas.read_json("...")
path=conf_path["path"]
data=spark.read_parquet(path.format(MONTH=month, DAY=day))
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74114097/2) to the question [using variable (f)-string stored in json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74114097/using-variable-f-string-stored-in-json) by the OP [Florida Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6510273/florida-man) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>